# firebase query by array of child

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have this document structure

```
{
  "parking" : {
    "-Kace9LLJBuhG1RBWsy2" : {
      "address" : "avenida",
      "company_name" : "Company",
      "hours" : 40,
      "owner" : "Fmex7wiYAsbxNFhDy39X1r28J9L2",
      "receipts" : [
         {
          "id" : "-KbB-0Wxxx_vsCxy",
          "date" : "3/01/2017",
          "user_id" : "Fmex7wiYAsbxNFhDy39X1r28J9L2",
          "value" : 50
        },
        {
          "id" : "-KbB-0Wzzzz_vsCy",
          "date" : "3/30/2017",
          "user_id" : "Fmex7wiYAsbxNFhDy39X1r28J9L2",
          "value" : 50
        }
      ],
      "social_name" : "Company",
      "value" : "50"
    },
```

Is it possible for me to pick up a parking lot, using the id of a receipt?
Example: I want to show the user a parking only if the user ID is inside the receipts array

Or do not you want to do this with the firebase and I would have to create a reference instead of a subdocument?

**EDIT**

I've tried something like:

```
var refParkingByUser = firebase.database().ref('parking').orderByChild('receipts').equalTo(Auth.$getAuth().uid);
```

But how do I access the receipt elements?

Comment: Nope. That query is not possible: Firebase Database queries query the children under the location where you run them, but the path you query under each child has to be fixed/static.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir

Answer (score 0):

As Frank mentioned you can't do that with your data. If you add in another node that looks like this:

```
{
    "recieptParkingLots": {
        "-KbB-0Wxxx_vsCxy": {
            "-Kace9LLJBuhG1RBWsy2": true
        },
        "-KbB-0Wzzzz_vsCy": {
            "-Kace9LLJBuhG1RBWsy2": true
        }
    }
}
```

You'd easily be able to find which parking lots a receipt is attached too.

If you can only have one receipt per parking lot I'd store them outside the parking lot node:

```
{
    "parking" : {
        "-Kace9LLJBuhG1RBWsy2" : {
            "address" : "avenida",
            "company_name" : "Company",
            "hours" : 40,
            "owner" : "Fmex7wiYAsbxNFhDy39X1r28J9L2",
            "receipts" : {
                "-KbB-0Wxxx_vsCxy" : true,
                "-KbB-0Wzzzz_vsCy" : true
            }
            "social_name" : "Company",
            "value" : "50"
        },
    }
    "receipts" : {
        "-KbB-0Wxxx_vsCxy" : {
            "parking" : "-Kace9LLJBuhG1RBWsy2",
            "date" : "3/01/2017",
            "user_id" : "Fmex7wiYAsbxNFhDy39X1r28J9L2",
            "value" : 50
        },
        "-KbB-0Wzzzz_vsCy" : {
            "parking" : "-Kace9LLJBuhG1RBWsy2",
            "date" : "3/30/2017",
            "user_id" : "Fmex7wiYAsbxNFhDy39X1r28J9L2",
            "value" : 50
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can easily look up the parking lot and then go and get the receipt.